# Marking an Agent as abstract?

Tags: anylogic

Can `Agents` in AnyLogic be marked as `abstract`? If so, how? I'm trying to inherit certain methods from an `Agent`, but not others as it makes no sense for the parent `Agent` to have them implemented.

Comment: Your question would be a better one if it contained some illustrative code.

Comment: It's a yes/no question, though. Can they be abstract, or can't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare anything `abstract` (class or method (AnyLogic function)) in a **GUI-designed Agent**, but you can create an Agent as a user-defined Java class (i.e., via New --> Java Class) which is `abstract`. You need to know the appropriate constructor signatures to do so, which AnyLogic doesn't document (but you can see them easily enough by viewing the generated Java code for any Agent). You'll therefore want something like the below (note the default constructor which seems never to be used):

```
public abstract class MyAbstractAgent extends Agent
                                implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Constructor in form required for an Agent subclass to be instantiated and for
     * superclass instantiation (as gleaned from looking at Java source of
     * visually-created Agents)
     */
    public MyAbstractAgent(Engine engine,
                           Agent owner,
                           AgentList<? extends MyAbstractAgent> collection) {

        super (engine, owner, collection);

    }

    /*
     * Simple constructor as now included in all AnyLogic 7 generated Agent code. Don't
     * understand when this would be invoked cf. the others so let's assert that we 
     * don't think it should
     */
    public MyAbstractAgent() {

        throw new AssertionError("Not expecting simple constructor to be used!");

    }

    // Using package visibility (the default for GUI-designed functions)
    abstract specialAbstractFunction();

}
```

However, since you probably want to mix in non-abstract methods, it would be preferable to have these in a GUI-designed Agent (so the class above `extends MyGUI_Agent` or similar), but this means having an abstract Agent which **just** has abstract methods (and thus one 'unnecessary' level of inheritance).

An alternative is just to 'approximate' abstract classes by forcing **run-time** conformance to (overridden) methods being required in any subclass Agent. Just define your required-in-subclass-Agent function in the parent as something like:

```
throw new IllegalStateException("Subclass must implement specialAbstractMethod()");
```

(or, better, throw your own `MissingRequiredOverrideException` or similar).
Not one for the purist but then neither is the other method.

Comment: I've taken the latter route as it makes more sense (debatable :P) in the AnyLogic context -- at least for future maintainers -- plus it's easier. This is exactly what I was looking for -- thank you!

Comment: OK, great. I did a minor edit 'for posterity' to clarify what I meant re mixing abstract and non-abstract methods. (It made sense before I think but just for completeness...)